# How to add token in url without showing it to the client when opened

Tags: php, email, url

I am using Php mailer and I have this link `<a href = 'project/welcome/signup.php?email=$email'>` in the body of the email.

In which `$email` here is equivalent to `youareawesome@gmail.com`.

Now what I want is that, when the client clicks that link he will be redirected to that link and I want the url to be like this `<a href = 'project/welcome/signup.php?email=sldkf3dlk32302'>` in which this value `sldkf3dlk32302` is equivalent to `youareawesome@gmail.com`. And then put the email to one of the textbox in that page. I want this for security purposes.

Could this be possible? Many thanks.

Comment: Create a token for the email and store it in a db put that in the URL

Comment: what about using mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt?

Comment: How am i able to do that? Can you please explain. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like you can treat the email with the same level of security you treat a password: using BCRYPT algorithm.

If you use [this lib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) the code would be something like:

```
$hash = password_hash($email, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

<a href='project/welcome/signup.php?email=$hash'
```

Another way is that you just [encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) the password. This way you can [decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) in the other end. To learn about the differences between these two options check it out [this post](https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/).

Comment: Thanks for this one, but how am i able to get the value of email and put this on the textbox on that page `'project/welcome/signup.php?email=$hash'`?

Comment: In my opinion you have a contradiction. You want security in the email in the url, but then on the page you just show the email. If you really want this you can store on the database the plain email and the hashed version, then use one to search the other.

Comment: Still don't have idea about storing to the database and get the email or token. How am I able to do that? Could you please help me?

Comment: Well I don't know the details of your implementation, but are you not using any database to store data? Just store the email in a column and the hashed version in another . Then you just use ``select``.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the option to just encrypt the password, cause I think what you really need in this case is mcrypt. Read the php documentation about the ``mcrypt_encrypt`` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help i'll just study on how to do this mcrypt_encrypt method.